# Keeping an Android app "awake" long enough to save data

Tags: android, multitasking, keep-alive

I'm not 100% sure this is necessary on Android.

For iOS, if your app goes into the background, and you're saving a large chunk of data, the app can sleep before the data is fully saved.  To get around this, you have to create some kind of Background Task "keepalive" thing in order to stop your app from shutting down.

Is there an equivalent for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a wake lock:

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock

---

**EDIT:**

Sounds like you want to do [work in the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/background), and then probably with [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).

Comment: Hm, that doesn't sound exactly like what I'm looking for... I'm trying to keep the app itself from going idle until it finishes writing out the big file it needs to write.  So the app behavior is... user presses home button, app gets signal, app processes and writes a big file, and then app can sleep.  On iOS, the OS will shut down the app before this can complete, without intervention.  On Android, it seems to complete anyway, but I want to make sure I don't have to specifically request extra time like on Apple.

Comment: Check my update.